# worth to learn groovy?

Tags: language-agnostic, groovy

the question im asking, is it worth to learn a new language like groovy? cause if i learn groovy, it feels like i code in groovy and not java. and how smart is that when i have to be good in java to code desktop applications too in the future. so if i use groovy a lot for web applications, i will just be worse and have to start over to be good in java when i code desktop applications right?

so why don´t I just stick with java and be good at ONE language instead of having to switch between 2 languages and their syntax. Cause it would be so confusing...

Comment: People routinely are fluent in five or six languages, and there is no evidence that learning one more is detrimental to the others. Another assumption in your question is that you will "have to be good in java to code desktop applications". If it's in a couple more years, maybe the next application you code will not even be in Java!

Comment: Suppose you knew only COBOL, and the choice was whether to learn Java.  Would you still have preferred to not learn a new language?  If you would have learned a new language in the COBOL case, what's different about this situation to make you avoid it?

Comment: Retagging as language-agnostic, since this doesn't really have anything to do with Java or Groovy

Comment: Surely this must be a duplicate of the idea "what are the benefits of knowing a portfolio of languages" ?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: You must know different people from the ones I know! At work, I'm surrounded by folks who barely know *one* language! This is a large corporate environment, I must admit, with almost tenure-like job security - so people don't bother advancing their skills much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quote:

> so why don´t I just stick with java
>   and be good at ONE language instead of
>   having to switch between 2 languages
>   and their syntax.

This seems like a more general question about learning programming languages than learning a new language (Groovy) which runs on top of the Java Virual Machine.

Here's a question:

Suppose you are learning a foreign language because you want to be fluent in multiple languages so you can converse with many people. You're learning German right now, but you're getting good at it, but you also want to learn Spanish. Would you just suddenly forget German if you start to learn Spanish? If you are indeed worried that you will, what would you do?

If you were going to learn Groovy, but don't want to forget how to write Java, then why not continue to use both languages at the same time?

One of the things about being a programmer is going to be learning to adapt to new technologies as they come along. It's a good thing to be able to learn new languages, as it's going to be a skill that's going to be very useful in a field which is constantly changing.

Answer (score 48):

Groovy is a nice, scriptable and easier-to-use Java "knockoff" – and I don't mean that derogatively. while Java is a language to be compiled, deployed and (often) run on Enterprise servers where performance matters, Groovy is a language where you can quickly create a program to get something done. Often that something is fairly simple, so it's an hour's or a day's coding effort. Often the code is only run once and then thrown away. Because Java has more boilerplate and formalism in it, you can do this kind of program more quickly and hence more efficiently in Groovy.

However, just to give you some perspective, Groovy is a relative newcomer stomping on the turf of various other, better established scripting languages:

- Perl is one of the grandfathers of scripting languages; rarely does a Unix server get installed without Perl on it, and Perl scripts are the lifeblood of many servers. However, Perl is a write-only language that looks like line noise to the uninitiated. There's more than one way to do everything, so styles diverge drastically. Perl coding tends to be a bit messy.
- Python is a fresher, cleaner script language than Perl, and is these days preferred by many as a scripting language. It's fun to program in, it gets things done and because it's been around for a few years, lots of people know it. Python is found behind/inside a number of Linux system utilities.
- Groovy leaves Perl and Python in the dust when (a) the environment already makes use of a JVM and/or there's a requirement to use existing Java code, including libraries. So far so good. Groovy is not blazingly fast, but faster than Python. Being dynamically typed, it's "fun" and "easy" to program in a way that Java's not.
- But then came Scala. Scala is like Java on steroids. It is statically typed so it's not quite as "fun" to program as Groovy, but it has type inference so often you can leave off the types and the compiler can figure them out. Scala works really hard to make the most of types; it does generic types a lot more seamlessly than Java. It dispenses with a lot of Java's boilerplate, so Scala programs are typically about 30% shorter than similar Java programs. Scala runs on the JVM and interfaces pretty well with Java code. It also runs about as quickly as Java, which most of the other languages don't.
- Finally in historic order, there's Clojure. Clojure is a Lisp derivative, so it has a programming style very different from languages you'd otherwise know, and it burns through a lot of parentheses! But Clojure runs on the JVM, is *very* compatible with all the rest of Java, and it's dynamically typed. You can use it as a scripting language or treat it like a compiled language... it's up to you. I find it fun to program in, and the fact that it's an almost pure functional language forces you to think in new ways about programming. It hurts your head at the beginning, but if you survive it's a very worthwhile exercise because you learn some techniques that will become more relevant (I think) in future programming.

In summary, it would probably do you good (put hair on your chest, if I may be so sexist) to learn one or more of these "alternative" / "scripting" languages. You may find them useful. Usually when there's something to be hacked up quickly in my project, I get the job because all my colleagues only know Java, and by the time they finish setting up their class framework I'm already done.

Comment: @CarlSmotricz Wow I really like your answer, because I have to learn groovy for my internship. But on a side note, would you recommend clojure and/or scala if I want to learn or experience and understand functional programming?

Comment: @Abdul: In Scala, functional programming is an option, but you could write completely imperative code if you wanted to. In Clojure, you're mostly forced to program functionally. This will make your first steps harder, maybe, but you will learn FP more quickly. Jumping into the cold water and all that. Other "very functional" alternatives (that I haven't tried) would be F#, Ocaml or Haskell.

Comment: As now we are writing 2017, is there something you would extend with or update this excellent answer?

Comment: @TamásG.: Good question, thank you! OK, I had forgotten to mention Lua, a tiny language one can use as a scripting language, and Ruby, a larger and more popular one also sometimes used for scripting. R is mostly for statistics but has enjoyed a meteoric rise in that sector. I personally dislike JavaScript but it's become _the_ language to know, it's taking over the world! Scripting included. Groovy, meanwhile, has had a lukewarm reception. I like Go! It's strictly compiled, but so quickly that some folks use it like a scripting language.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you code your desktop apps in groovy too? Just because groovy is the choice of a web framework (grails) doesn't mean that you can't use it for desktop apps.

Indeed, it is great for desktop apps too. It's more a matter of dynamic or static languages...

In my opinion, it is quite good to have for each task the right language at hand. So go ahead and learn groovy - the result will be that you'll miss groovy features when you try to use java again ;-)

Comment: ok i didn't know that. with static language one means that you have to define the data types of the variables? and with a dynamic language you don't have to?

Comment: Correct. Actually, the formal terms are "statically typed" and "dynamically typed".

Comment: @Carl: If you want to be pedantic, "dynamic typing" is a contradiction.

Comment: I don't think so. IIRC dynamic type means the compiler infers their type during runtime. So they are typed dynamically.

Comment: @skaffman: I only wax pedantic when that helps me make somebody else look stupid. So in this case I'll gladly pass ;)

Answer (score 4):

I would say in general in this field it's always good to be learning.  I try constantly to learn new concepts to add to my toolbox, while getting better at the core things I'm interested in like Java.  I recently purchased a book on learning Clojure - another functional language for the JVM.

The downside to learning something without using it every day is that some details don't stick in your head.  That said, I'm glad I spent some time with Clojure; the important stuff stuck and I know I can quickly look up the details if and when I need to.  You may want to take a similar approach to Groovy.

Answer (score 3):

The Java platform is slowly starting to change direction to one where the JVM is targeted by multiple source languages (a trick .net has been showing off since day 1, but it's taking Java a while to catch up there). The Java7 classfile format is even adding a new instruction to make these dynamic languages work faster.

If you want to keep yourself current, then learning Groovy is a good way to do it, without abandoning all your investment in the Java platform.

Furthermore, Groovy (and Grails) is now maintained by SpringSource, so its popularity is only going to increase.

Comment: The JVM has supported multiple languages since it's inception and there have been alternative JVM languages for a long time, e.g. JRuby has been around since 2001 and Jython since 1997

Comment: I didn't claim otherwise. But they've had no explicit support from the JVM until now. Java7 adds a `invokespecial` bytecode instruction that allows dynamic languages to be better optimised.

Comment: I think devs were able to create a new language on JVM since its day 1 too. Plus, Spring framework can be used on multiple languages too, for examples, Java and Groovy

Answer (score 3):

Going from java to groovy isn't a lot of work. No where near what would be needed to move to a less Javaish language like clojure.

I really like groovy for one-off apps and for scripting existing java code. I've used it to parse data from REST calls and feed the data to a JMS queue. I've used it to create scrambled test data for a partner from our production data. For stuff like that it is amazing.

If the goal is to learn a dynamic language to add to the toolbox, Python and Ruby are both good choices. They run on the JVM and have native versions. Both are well supported on a large number of platforms.

If the goal is to learn an alternative JVM language, groovy is an excellent choice. Both Scala and Clojure would also be good choices.

I used to stick to the "learn a new language every year rule" from The Pragmatic Programmer, but that was before I had kids. Now I learn a new building toy every six months.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'm this is a highly subjective question.

In my humble opinion it is worth learning a new language especially if it varies in paradigms (as is the case with groovy). I'm fairly young myself so for me learning a new language is not a much of hassle but the way I see it if you like the language, you estimate that coding in language X will be profitable you should learn it.

It won't hurt your resume.
It won't make your head hurt (much).
The only problem is, will you use it. You need to use a language to become good at it. If you are going to learn it now and never use it tomorrow it probably ain't worth learning it.

Answer (score 1):

Learning something new does not take away something you already know.  You may be a bit rusty when you get back into Java, but it'll come back real quick.

Also--

I'm not a Java guy, but I believe Groovy targets the JVM.  If this is the case, then programming in Groovy will make you a better Java programmer, because you'll still be targeting the same framework as Java (the language) so you'll still continue to gain experience with the Java libraries.  Knowing the available libraries is what really matters, not how well you know every minute detail of a particular language.

Answer (score 1):

I find that by learning new languages, I always end up learning new ways to think about problems. Each language guides you into solving problems in the way most easily expressed by the language. Learning new languages only makes you stronger all around because you learn new ways to solve problems.

You might have to re-orient yourself with the libraries after a long time away from a language, but even then it's not a huge ordeal - just more frequent google searches, etc.

The benefits, however, are worth it. I recently did some functional programming for the first time and it really taught me a lot of different ways to think about certain situations. I find myself now using some of C#'s functional aspects and it makes my code a lot cleaner in some cases. The bottom line is; if your going to do this for a living you are going to want to learn more than one language, have you ever met a mechanic that only knew one make and model of car?

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to learn a new language to be a better programmer. Groovy is a natural choice for java programmer - easy to learn and you can still use your all java knowlege.

Groovy is a dynamic language, after try to learn any functional language (like Scala). With this experience you will see java from different perspecitve. Some task that was painful in Java will be trivial in Groovy/Scala.

Comment: you can mix them in your code like javascript and jquery?

Comment: Yes, that's the power. You can call groovy form java and java from groovy. Having more 'tools' give you a choice to choose a right tool for a job.

Comment: @noname: jquery is not a programming language, it's a "class" written in javascript.  you're not mixing anything when you use jquery in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can program desktop aplication with Griffon whose language of choice is Groovy, give it a try

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for online help, check this websites:

- for [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Getting+Started+Guide)
- for [Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/)